# Is it graph bipartition

Tags: graph

Given M food and N person. Each person has their own fav food. Find minimum food to support all persons for their breakfast

example :

```
           f1   f2  f3 \n
```

p1             1     1    0 \n

p2             0     0    1 \n

p3             0     1    0 \n

answer is 2since f2 supports 2 persons and f3 support 1 person

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unclear what you are asking here as you are not explicitly posing any questions except for the one in the heading.

This is obviously a bipartite graph, yes, but the problem you are trying to solve is not a matching problem, but rather the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

In order to see this, make a set for each food consisting of the persons that eats this food. In your example you will get the three sets {p1}, {p1, p3} and {p2} (who likes f1, f2 and f3, respectively). Finding the minimal number of these sets that together cover all of your persons, that is the set {p1, p2, p3}, is exactly an instance of the set cover problem.